# btrfs contains much more data that fi df claims

Tags: btrfs

Sorry, I know this btrfs df question #1012819281.

I converted my data grave from ext4 to btrfs (due to the need for incremential backups). I used a Ubuntu Trusty live system, since there is a warning about conversion with btrfs 4. As far as I can see, everything went well, looking at the data. However btrfs fi df /data shows

```
Data, single: total=1.71TiB, used=1.70TiB
System, single: total=32.00MiB, used=140.00KiB
Metadata, single: total=613.00GiB, used=585.60GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

So Metadata is huge. I read the questions about that, balanced the metadata (-m, -musage=0, even a full balance) and also did a scrub. No change

What really puzzles me is this:

```
root@home-le:/data# du -hd0
2.3T    .
```

This is the expected amount of data from the old ext4 drive, but it is much more that df above shows.
So ... can anybody explain what is going on here?

Comment: 1.7TiB (data) + 0.6TiB (metadata) = 2.3TiB. I do not know whether that is coincidence or the right answer though.

Comment: Me neither. But it was already 2.3TB on the ext4 filesystem. I cannot really imagine that ext4 has that much (many?) metadata. Also, while there are quite a lot of small files from maildirs, 1.7TB are made up from files between 1 and 10GB, so there are not THAT many in a major portion of the data.